# Is there a way to have the MAX function read both text and numbers?

Tags: excel

I currently have a spreadsheet where I am collecting data each week. I want to find the max value in each week and record it automatically.

The issue is that I am concatenating an asterisk to the end of the data point if data hasn't been recorded that week for that specific station. So if the previous week I recorded 50, and this week I didn't record anything for that station, it auto fills the data point with 50* to signify I didn't look at that station and that that information is auto filled from the previous week.

I'm using this function to find the MAX in each column:

```
=IF(MAX(K6:K54)=0,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1),MAX(K6:K54))
```

and this is an example of a data point in that column:

```
=CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1)=0," ",CONCATENATE(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1),"*")),"*",""),"*")
```

Essentially what is happening is that the MAX value is ignoring a value with an asterisk, which I want it to include in each column. If I have a column of 41, 32, 46*, and 52*, it says the max is 41, when I want it to say 52. Not sure if this is possible, but maybe I haven't thought of something. Anything helps at this point. Thanks :)

Comment: As long as there are no blanks in K6:K54 and ALL entries are either numbers (such as 41, 32) or numbers with an asterisk (such as 46*, 52*), then this will work for you: `=MAX(INDEX(--SUBSTITUTE(K6:K54,"*",""),))`

Comment: HEY THAT WORKED THANKS!

Comment: Wait after a second glance, it seems that it isn't working. Am I doing this correctly?

`
=IF(MAX(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q54,"*",""),))=0,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1),MAX(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q54,"*",""),)))
`

Comment: you're missing the double unary `--` which is what converts the values to numbers.

Comment: When I do that, I get #VALUE!

Comment: =IF(MAX(INDEX(--SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q54,"*",""),))=0,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1),MAX(INDEX(--SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q54,"*",""),)))

Comment: If you are getting the `#VALUE!` error, it means that one of the cells in range `Q6:Q54` is blank or contains text beyond the asterisk.  Can you please edit your question to provide better sample data?

Comment: However, you can use this **array** formula to ignore blanks and text: `=MAX(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q54,"*",""),0))`.  Note that as an array formula it is required that it be confirmed with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` instead of just `Enter`.

Comment: In the range, I have numbers (41, 32), numbers with asterisks (46* and 57*), and then just cells with only asterisks (*). Are the cells with just asterisks messing this up?

Comment: Yes, though the array formula would be able to deal with those.

Comment: =IF(MAX(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q45,"*",""),0))=0,OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1),MAX(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(Q6:Q45,"*",""),0)))

Comment: IT doesn't work :(. It doesn't seem to update at all

Comment: Note that as an array formula it is required that it be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter. See [here](https://www.vertex42.com/blog/excel-formulas/array-formula-examples.html) for more info.

Comment: Oh I have to do that in the equation bar. Once I do that though, it will always automatically update the values?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok thank you so much!